# Oracle Cloud error apt-get update

Tags: server, updates, cloud

Hello friends: im on Canonical-Ubuntu-20.04-aarch64 / oracle cloud / ssh

Im trying to update and upgrade the repos and i get this problem. Please help me, im a noob.

```
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
Err:2 http://uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
Err:3 http://uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to uk-london-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the instance is permitted to access the Internet? This looks more like a network firewall issue than anything in Ubuntu itself 